# <testResources> ignored on junits

Tags: spring-boot

I must be going wrong somewhere - but when i add snippet below and run a junit, i am not seeing the classpath getting updated to include the directory. Eg. I am doing a `getClass().getResource("..")` and getting a NPE. I was doing the same flow in standard spring apps with no issues, and only noticed after migrating to boot.

Is test resource supported when running mvn surefire:test ? Eg. I have some stub results that I used only in junits, and prefer to package next to the code that is leveraging rather then another folder.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration> </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <!-- support for eclipse and maven junit -->
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>

    </testResources>

</build>
```

Comment: There's no reason that surefire wouldn't pick up the complete classpath. You can also check `target/test-classes` to make sure the resource you're trying to locate is there.

Comment: maven will not copy non-java files to test-classes (eg. myresults.json), that is i think delegated to maven resources plugin. But with boot - it does not appear that when invoke via surefire test the resources are copied.. In a non-boot project - this is not the case. so I did,update the surefire settings for boot projects to workaround

Comment: <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: Something else must be different between the two projects. Can you share a sample that shows the problem?